# error in pipeline deployment

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, deployment

Using this URL https://blog.e-zest.com/magento-2-pipeline-deployment-with-minimum-downtime I have followed all steps for dev and build server, then now when I am running php bin/magento app:config:import in production server which is trying to access config dump that is created in dev server on step number 7, I am getting "error: Import failed: Connection "default" is not defined"

Does anyone has a direction or a solution

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like `app/etc/env.php` hasn't been populated with db connection credentials?
You want something like

```php
<?php
return array (
  'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),
  'db' => 
  array (
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'HOST',
        'dbname' => 'DATABASE',
        'username' => 'USERNAME',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
    'table_prefix' => '',
  ),
  'crypt' => 
  array (
    'key' => 'crypt_key',
  ),
  'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'files',
  ),
  'resource' => 
  array (
    'default_setup' => 
    array (
      'connection' => 'default',
    ),
  ),
  'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
  'cache_types' => 
  array (
    'config' => 1,
    'layout' => 1,
    'block_html' => 1,
    'collections' => 1,
    'reflection' => 1,
    'db_ddl' => 1,
    'eav' => 1,
    'customer_notification' => 1,
    'target_rule' => 1,
    'full_page' => 1,
    'eav_attribute_options' => 1,
    'fredhopper' => 1,
    'config_integration' => 1,
    'config_integration_api' => 1,
    'translate' => 1,
    'config_webservice' => 1,
    'compiled_config' => 1,
  ),
  'install' => 
  array (
    'date' => 'Thu, 1 Jan 1991 10:41:56 +0000',
  ),
);
```

Though you will prolly want to add varnish and redis to that :)